# Error React, package.json

Tags: reactjs, vscode

Estoy tratando de desarrollar mi primera `app` en `React`.

En `VSCode`, cuando ejecuto ***npm start***, todo funciona bien, pero apenas guardo algun cambio, me envía el siguiente error.

> ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\laura\onedrive\escritorio\alkemy\presupuesto-personal\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\laura\OneDrive\Escritorio\Alkemy\presupuesto-personal\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
> webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 1 error in 4677 ms

Traté con ***npm run update***, que leí en las preguntas en inglés y no funciona.

Comment: Como solución generica te aconsejo que intentes ejecutar el comando `npm install` para actualizar tus dependencias y ver si eso corrige el error. Si eso no funciona, puedes eliminar la carpeta `node_modules` y volver a ejecutar luego `npm install` para reinstalar todas las dependencias.

Comment: `yarn remove eslint-config-react-app`
o `npm uninstall eslint-config-react-app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vi que el error está en escribir mal el path, fijate : laura\OneDrive... en el segundo y en el primero es : \laura\onedrive... te daras cuenta que no son iguales, onedrive != OneDrive. Lo saque de aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227342/plugin-react-was-conflicted-between-package-json-and-baseconfig